# Exit modal using css by clicking outside main box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created this modal popup using only css, however I can only leave it if I click on "X". I want to add the option to leave the modal when the user clicks outside the main box, ie, clicks the grey area.

Any suggestions on how it can be done?

Is it necessary to use JQuery?
So far the code is really simple, that's why I'm trying to avoid it.

```
  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="#close">X</a>
        <h1>Modal Box</h1>
        <button ng-click="changeState()">Show Client</button>
        <div ng-if="client.state">{{client.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Plunker to check the whole thing](https://plnkr.co/edit/MBp5OnV1QR1sCaytCYBV?p=preview)

Thank you :)

Comment: Why note use `ng-click` again ?

Comment: @SergeK. and trigger what exactly? :)

Comment: Change `<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">` => `<a id="openModal" class="modalDialog" href="#close">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a link behind the content that takes all window size, and you set the same `href` than your close button:

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
      <a class="fullSizeBlock" href="#close">&nbsp;</a>
      <div class="content">
          <a href="#close">X</a>
          <h1>Modal Box</h1>
          <button ng-click="changeState()">Show Client</button>
        <div ng-if="client.state">{{client.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS added (cursor is not mandatory, you can leave default link pointer):

```
.fullSizeBlock{
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you beat me with few second by the same idea :) but it tooks me time to put it live here :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif it took me a little time too because i tested it in the plunker first.. you'll have it next time ;) good coding to you!

Comment: no it's not a battle :) just joking because you got exactly the same as mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can add another `a` element that will behave as a layer and when you click on it, it will hide the modal:

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("demo", []);

angular
  .module("demo")
  .controller("demoCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.client = {
      name: "John Doe",
      state: false
    };
    $scope.changeState = function() {
      $scope.client.state = !$scope.client.state;
    }
  }]);
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* CSS of new element */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
/*   */
.modalDialog .content {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <!-- New element here -->
    <a href="#close" class="close"></a>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="#close">X</a>
      <h1>Modal Box</h1>
      <button ng-click="changeState()">Show Client</button>
      <div ng-if="client.state">{{client.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. Someone answered before so I had to accept his answer. I upvoted yours though ;)